# injecting test mock data into protractor mock module

Tags: angularjs, protractor, angular-mock

In my protractor e2e tests, I want to use mock data for `httpBackendMock`. However I am not able to access/inject the data into mock module. Below is my coffee code.

```
describe 'my test page', ->
  ptor = protractor.getInstance()
  page = require('./pages/FooPage.js')
  fooPage = new page()
  data = require('./data/testdata.json').data

  describe 'happy path', ->
    beforeEach ->
      httpBackendMock = ->
        angular.module('httpBackendMock', ['ngMockE2E', 'fooApp.controllers']).run ($httpBackend) ->
          mockData = data
```

Line `mockData = data` fails (complains `data` is not defined) when I run the test.
I understand this is due to the different context of execution according to 
https://github.com/angular/protractor/issues/509

So how do I specify the mock data variable in my angular mock module? I do not want to hard code the data in the test.

Comment: Any protractor experts???

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Found the solution using [http-backend-proxy](https://github.com/kbaltrinic/http-backend-proxy)

```
describe 'my test page', ->
  page = require('./pages/FooPage.js')
  httpBackend = require('http-backend-proxy')
  fooPage = new page()
  mockData = require('./data/testdata.json')

  describe 'my test steps', ->
    beforeEach ->
      proxy = new httpBackend(browser)
      proxy.onLoad.whenGET('/foo/v1/userinfo').respond(200, mockData)
      proxy.onLoad.whenGET(/.*/).passThrough()
      fooPage.get()
      browser.driver.manage().window().maximize()

    describe 'main page scenarios', ->
      it 'scenario 1', ->
        usual expect and toBe stuff
```